# combining datatype and objectype properties OWL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology

I want to combine the instance (results) associated with two different property types. I can combine them using SPARQL, but I would like to define it the model itself. I am not sure what is the best way to accomplish it. Let me provide you a concrete example.

I have two classes (:book, :tag), an objecttype property (:hasTag), and a datatype property (:hasDescription) with strings.
Instances are defined as:

```
:book1 a :book .
:semantics a :tag .
:book1 :hasTag :semantics .
:book1 :hasDescription "book about web technology" .
:book1 :hasDescription "good for all level of users" .
:book1 :hasDescription "has examples from biomedical industries" .
```

There are other classes and properties as well. I would like to get the tag results (semantics) and description results ("book about web technology", "good for all level of users", "has examples from biomedical industries") for book1. Can it be done be defining another property and somehow linking the new property to hasTag and hasDescription ? or is there another/better way?

Also, on a separate note, I am assuming that two instances to a datatype property (as I did in the example) is fine. Please let me know if there are any concerns in this case.

Comment: What does this sentence mean: "I would like to get the tag results (semantics) and description results ("book about web technology", "good for all level of users", "has examples from biomedical industries") for book1." This sentence is missing something or I'm just not able to understand what exactly you mean by "I would like to get"

Comment: Basically :hasTag and :hasDescription provide additional information about the book. these properties are of different types (objecttype and datatype), because the first one can only accept tags from a fixed list (generic to all the books), while the second one accepts free-form text (provided by users).  I want to combine/access all information (tags & description) in the data model itself, using a reasoner perhaps and  defining a new property. Once the information is combined I can use the new property to  obtain the results, which can be used for advanced searching and other applications.

Comment: Hm, in OWL you can't "combine" literals and resources as the values of a single property. In RDF this would work indeed as properties are not typed in the RDF model. Using an intermediate node connected to `:book1` by a relation `:hasInformation` would introduce overhead when retrieving the data itself

Comment: Does it mean that the best way is to keep them separate instead of using property chains or some other options?

Comment: You can't use an OWL property chain over data properties. In general, we don't know your use-case later on, and so we don't know what/how you query the data. Note, an OWL reasoner is an inference engine, not really aimed to be used as a query engine. Retrieving data would need something like SPARQL.